# PrintWriter not appending content in the right order

Tags: java, io, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I have a list that contains objects (whose constructor contains another inner object). When I'm trying to print the list to a file, I go through each object and call the object's respective writer methods.

```
public void writer(String file, boolean append) {
    File path = new File("../Opdracht6_2/src/" + file);
    try {
        PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(path,
                append));
        for (SuperObject o : this.list) {
            if (o instanceof Object1) {
                ((subObject1) w).writer1(file);
            }
            if (o instanceof Object2) {
                ((subObject3) w).writer2(file);
                
            }if (o instanceof Object3) {
                ((subObject3) w).writer3(file);
                
            }
        }
        write.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the object's writer method I try to first print a line which says what type it is and then call the writer method for the innerobject. After that I want current object's arguments to be printed and than it goes back to the lists writer method

```
public void writer1(String file) {
    File path = new File("../Opdracht6_2/src/" + file);
    try {
        PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(path, true));
        //below is the string I want to print before the innerobject appends 
        //its own arguments to the file
        write.append("String\r\n");
        this.innerobject.innerwriter();
        write.append(this objects arg);
        write.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The innerobject's writer

```
public void innerwriter(String file) {
    File path = new File("../Opdracht6_2/src/" + file);
    try {
        PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(path, true));
        write.append(this objects arg);
        write.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the thing that is actually happening is that the line that I'm trying to append first gets appended after the innerobject's arguments even though I have put it before the method that calls the innerobject's writer.
It looks like this then in the file:

> inner objects arg
>
> string
>
> outer objects arg

Can someone explain why?

Comment: You should not open the same file multiple files simultaneously... Redesign the methods or after you write `string` flush and close the PrintWriter and then call `innerwriter` method or pass the `write` object to `innerwriter` method and use it to write instead of opening file again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better not to use a `Writer` in each method here. Use a single `StringBuilder` to append the content and pass it through the methods. It could be that the `Writer` is not properly flushing the contents in the order in which content is appended. Specifically, the statement `write.close()` inside `innerwriter` would flush the contents of the inner object before the `"String\r\n"` is actually written by the `Writer` in the caller method.

You can avoid creating multiple `Writer`s and use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
// pass a StringBuilder to append
public void innerwriter(StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.append(this objects arg);
}
```

And when you're done with appending all content, write it using the `Writer` created only once:

```
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(path,
            append));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (SuperObject o : this.list) {
    if (o instanceof Object1) {
        ((subObject1) w).writer1(sb);
    }
    if (o instanceof Object2) {
        ((subObject3) w).writer2(sb);

    } if (o instanceof Object3) {
        ((subObject3) w).writer3(sb);

    }
}

write.append(sb.toString());
write.close();
```